# Force "controller support" so game shows up in Big Picture

Tags: steam

I've got some old (and some new) games on Steam that fully/partially support controllers, but their devs haven't listed controller support in the steam store.

Is there any way to force these games into the controller support list? Making a separate category would be a possible work around, but I already categorize my games so this would be far from optimal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to be able to use your controller in a game that doesnt normally support a controller?

Comment: @TheBird956 no, I just want to force games that already support a controller ingame to show up in the "controller supported" list for Steam Big Picture. The games already run with controllers, but without that flag set they dont' show up in the category for easy browsing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you listed the specific games and whether they have full or partial controller support.  If that's not appropriate here, try:  http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamuniverse/discussions/0/

Comment: @BenJackson I've contacted the devs directly. Games so far are Gish (chronic Logic said they'd look into it, no change months later) and Long Live The Queen (dev said it should work but have no 360 controller to test...eesh.)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new catagory of your own, this can be looked at in big picture and you can choose whatever games you like in it even ones you have modded for controller support or third party games.

to do this right click on the game in your libary and click add catagory you will get a screen like this
[image]

Then give it a name e.g. "Controller Friendly"

then when you look in your library they will be seperated like this

[image]

and you can select specific catagories in big picture by clicking the drop down at the top shown in the picture below

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I already use categories, so this would really mess up my organization

Comment: you could use favourites specifically for controller programs, or create an extra catagory for each one for controller support. basically what i am saying is there is no way to force it to say something is supported because that info is taken from the steam store metadata. the only other option would be to add an icon to the pictures manually so you can spot them easily this could be done with a watermarking tool

Answer (score 0):

This seems not possible for the moment. Maybe in a future update but you're not alone wishing to have this feature.

http://steamcommunity.com/groups/bigpicture/discussions/1/558747218087145752/

http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/846938351041439806/